# Price computation cache solution

Tags: mysql, caching, redis, memcached

The price calculations for the product I rent out is very complicated, and basically signature for it looks like this:

`price = f( from_date, to_date, x )` - i.e dependent on 3 parameters: `from_date`, `to_date`, `x`, where `from_date` and `to_date` are dates, and `x` is a numeric (int) value in range from 1 to 10.

`f` - is the complicated underlying function.

Main constraints:

1) `from_date` accept values [ today; today + 1 year ]

2) `to_date` > `from_date`

3) |(`to_date` - `from_date`)| takes values from [1..365]

I use MySQL as my main storage and I have around 50,000 items.

And I would like to build a search page, where you could filter or sort by price (after entering dates; `x` defaults to 1 if omitted).

I understand that this cannot be converted into MySQL query, because it is too complicated (and even if was possible, it would be very slow and inefficient).

I thought that maybe I could use a key-value storage like `redis` or `memcache` to pre-calculate price values for all possible date ranges, store them there, and invalidate if needed (and that will not happen often).

But, using some basic math, I figured out that using this approach I would need at most 33,580,500,000 keys: `(366 * 367 / 2) * 10 * 50,000`

And my question is - I'm I thinking in right direction? 
If yes - are there any efficient solutions (in terms of # of keys, memory footprint and scalability) to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish as a result... `from_date`, `to_date` ... what are you comparing this to? Could you add the relevant part of the table structure, so we can understand better?

Comment: @EdwinKrause 

Basically I have pricing calendars for the items I rent out. 

But it's kinda involved to understand it all: fees, discount systems - it's really complicated. 
 
The result I want to achieve - I wan't to be able to use "sort" and "filter" on a search page. For that I need to have prices pre-computed. Because doing it every single time for all the items will just kill my application. Tried it already - it's super slow.

Comment: Still would be interesting to see your table structure. I hope you store that info in more than one table. If you have a proper structure I believe you can accomplish this with MySQL queries

Comment: @EdwinKrause discounts, fees, items themselves are stored in separate DB tables, of course.  
I will be able to show it only tomorrow. 
Meanwhile I would like to know still if any key-value storage is applicable?

And no, I don't feel like using MySQL query - it's super involved. Discounts have many constraints to be applied, and discount calculations are complicated. I had enough problems implementing in ruby. :)

Comment: Well, personally I don't think it makes sense. With a system you rent out products you don't really have to reinvent the wheel. It's not that complicated of a system, no matter if you rent out 7 cars or 50000 items of whatever you're renting out.

Comment: @EdwinKrause what do you mean to "reinvert the wheel"?
Problem is not with 50,000 items - it's nothing. 
But counting the price for individual item given (from_date, to_date, x) input vector is NOT fun at all.

And I have idea what I'm I talking about - used to have a MySQL solution, before implemented these two sub-systems.

Comment: I believe you that it's challanging, but we need to see your structure, in order to help you